# SAS - change format to day/month

Tags: date, sas, format

I have a date format like `ddmmyyd10.`
Is want a format that only shows day and month like this dd/mm
is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use a length of 5 instead

```
data _null_;
   dt = '22dec2020'd;
   put dt ddmmyy5.;
run;
```